# Grouping payment types and totaling the sum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please zero in on the 'payment information' portion and the 'payment by type' portion in the spreadsheet clip below to follow along with my question.

My goal is to **sum up all** the like payment types. When entering the data, the user can choose the payment type from a drop-down list then enter in the amount in the cell next to it.

For example,`'cash'` is chosen in two payment types below - one in the record '14' for the amount of $10, and one in the record '15' for the amount of $5, so the total should be $15 in the bottom `'Payment by Type'` summary. Furthermore, the `'Finance - TD'`
 should total $500 and `'CC - Visa'` should total $100 in the payment summaries. I'm not sure what formula to use to do this.

Can someone help? I imagine that I should use an `'if'` statement, but I'm not sure how to group the cells to do it. 
Something like

```
if(paymenttype = cash, cash_total += (cell))....idk
```

[image]

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? Was it because I didn't markdown correctly, or is the question bad? I can't refer to a cell with quote marks? I have to use backticks?Can someone explain my mistake so I can avoid them next time?

Comment: maybe its because you did not provide a copy/dummy of your sheet :)

Comment: Oops, yeah that makes sense.  ty for your help - @player0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your table looks like this then paste this formula to **J12** and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY($I$1:$J$10, "select sum(J) 
                            where I='"&I12&"'
                            label sum(J)''", 0), )
```

[image]